# Format Help for Javascript .click if Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I am new to Javascript and am trying to make a Javascript .click function. Upon clicking button id #btnTransfer, I want it to check against the listed account id value(s) and throw an error message if it matches a listed value. Here is the code im using. The user's input id #accountid is already printed on the webpage via asp, but is hidden from view. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```js
$('#btnTransfer').click(function () {
  if ($('#accountid').val() == "123456789") {
    popError("Error you cannot preform this action");
}
```

Comment: What is the issue? Is the click being called? Is the value being read? Is the method `popError` defined? Is that the exact code? Impossible to help you with the info given.

Answer (score 0):

your code is write https://api.jquery.com/click/ i dont understand what u really want to do explain me more or give us more code

Comment: this would be better as a comment

Comment: @JaromandaX Probably it was a long time ago that you don't remember the strugle. The user do not have enough reputation to comment.

Comment: Been less than two years - so, not that long, and yes, I made the same mistake once, and was told exactly what I posted - so I built my reputation until I could comment - it wasn't a criticism, and I certainly did not downvote this answer

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing brace and closing parenthesis. Once those syntax issues are fixed and the reference to jQuery included, it works exactly as you said you wanted it to. I don't know what your `popError` function is like, so I just have it displaying an alert.

```js
function popError(message) {
    alert(message);
}

$('#btnTransfer').click(function () {
    if ($('#accountid').val() == "123456789") {
        popError("Error you cannot preform this action");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="btnTransfer">Transfer</button>

<input type="hidden" id="accountid" value="123456789" />
```